# Correct syntax of making a "class template" friend to a class

Tags: c++, syntax, class-template

I just need:

Correct syntax of making a "class template" friend to a class

Comment: Have you tried Googling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a class template, for example

```
template <typename> class Template;
```

you can either befriend a particular specialisation of the template:

```
friend class Template<int>;
```

or all specialisations:

```
template <typename> friend class Template;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a different typed friend class:

```
template<typename,typename> friend class ClassName;
```

Comment: so I need to use typename keyword and then use the template param's identifier?

Comment: It will make any templated version of ClassName the friend.

Comment: so if my class template be: template <typename T> class CT{};
its friend declaration in class C is: 
 template <typename T> friend class CT;
true?

Comment: yes. Although you don't have to specify the argument name (T) ... just the keyword "typename"

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can do this:

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
    friend T;
};
```

Comment: This isn't making a class template be a friend. This is making a class (`T`) be a friend.

Comment: You're correct, I misunderstood what he wanted, :)